# With express.js, what is the best way for images to load fast?

Tags: javascript, express, canvas, redis

Just want to ask, I am making an Image Generation Website and it uses node-canvas to create generate the images. Some endpoints use superagent to request (`GET`) other APIs and display the data on the image.

Currently, I don't have anything for the images to generate and load faster. It uses up a fair bit of my Memory and CPU on my project and can be a big problem for me if I don't implement this. I've looked up something about Redis for caching but I am using Glitch for developing it and it isn't supported there.

I've used the following express.js code after reading a guide on Server Side Caching.

In my image generation file: (e.g. blur.js)

```js
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=120');
```

One of my Router Files:

```js
const serveStatic = require('serve-static')

router.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {
  maxAge: '60',
  setHeaders: setCustomCacheControl

function setCustomCacheControl (res, path) {
  if (serveStatic.mime.lookup(path) === 'text/html' && "text/javascript") {
    // Custom Cache-Control for HTML files
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=60')
      console.log('Test')
  }
}
}))
```

I've tested the code above and it seemed to be it but I am not 100% certain its working (I even checked the Chrome Console for `ms` load differences). Well, if I add something like that, it will help benefit my Service that does image generation, JSON and Image Game Statistics Cards as it does not need to be requested over and over again and use a lot of Resources.

Comment: Have you considered caching?

Comment: Thats what I've explained above. I just need to know if its beneficial and if the code is working.